# Create list of ActionBlock<T> that will complete when any fail

Tags: c#, async-await, tpl-dataflow

In a scenario where await may be called on an 'empty' list of tasks.

How do I await a list of `Task<T>`, and then add new tasks to the awaiting list until one fails or completes.

I am sure there is must be an [`Awaiter`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661348/custom-awaitables-for-dummies) or [`CancellationTokenSource`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638952/cancellationtoken-and-cancellationtokensource-how-to-use-it) solution for this problem.

```
public class LinkerThingBob
{
    private List<Task> ofmyactions = new List<Task>();

    public void LinkTo<T>(BufferBlock<T> messages) where T : class
    {
        var action = new ActionBlock<IMsg>(_ => this.Tx(messages, _));

        // this would not actually work, because the WhenAny 
        // will not include subsequent actions.
        ofmyactions.Add(action.Completion);

        // link the new action block.
        this._inboundMessageBuffer.LinkTo(block);
    }

    // used to catch exceptions since these blocks typically don't end.
    public async Task CompletionAsync()
    {
        // how do i make the awaiting thread add a new action
        // to the list of waiting tasks without interrupting it
        // or graciously interrupting it to let it know there's one more

        // more importantly, this CompletionAsync might actually be called
        // before the first action is added to the list, so I actually need
        // WhenAny(INFINITE + ofmyactions)
        await Task.WhenAny(ofmyactions);
    }
}
```

My problem is that I need a mechanism where I can add each of the `action` instances created above to a `Task<T>` that will complete when there is an exception.

I am not sure how best to explain this but:

- The task must not complete until at least one call to `LinkTo<T>` has been made, so I need to start with an infinite task
- each time `LinkTo<T>` is called, the new action must be added to the list of tasks, which may already be awaited on in another thread.

Comment: Any reason why you dont just add your messages to a ConcurrentQueue and have a number of worker tasks popping from them? This way you have complete control over all the tasks in whatever happens. Syncing ActionsBlocks seems uneccessary clutterly to me.

Comment: I am using action blocks elsewhere and want to keep the pattern. Besides that there should be a way of coordinating multiple tasks in such a way that more can be added if necessary. Perhaps I have to build an add task callback / continuation. The problem is interesting nevertheless.

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

Comment: I have edited the question with a more complete reproduction of the essentials of the problem.
I hope it makes it clearer.

Comment: Creating an "infinite" task is very simple - just initialize a new task (for example `var t = new Task(()=> {})`)  and don't start it... Why not initializing `ofmyactions` with such a task in it?

Comment: @Jim: Did you mean `ofmyactions.Add(action.Completion);`? And do you want `CompletionAsync` to only complete if there's an exception?

Comment: @shay Thanks for that it certainly helps I had not considered that simple solution to the infinite task - it doesn't solve the rest of the problem though. I need add a new action to the list of awaiting tasks which the other thread responds to. That's the essence of the problem. A flexi-continuation for lack of a better term

Comment: @stephen, yes you're correct. The problem is that WhenAny takes an array. It's not mutable and I can't think of how to change it correctly. It doesn't have to end only on exception but that is how it typically ends, either that or the service terminates and cancels a token (left out for brevity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't anything built-in for this, but it's not too hard to build one using `TaskCompletionSource<T>`. TCS is the type to use when you want to await something and there isn't already a construct for it. (Custom awaiters are for more advanced scenarios).

In this case, something like this should suffice:

```
public class LinkerThingBob
{
  private readonly TaskCompletionSource<object> _tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

  private async Task ObserveAsync(Task task)
  {
    try
    {
      await task;
      _tcs.TrySetResult(null);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      _tcs.TrySetException(ex);
    }
  }

  public void LinkTo<T>(BufferBlock<T> messages) where T : class
  {
    var action = new ActionBlock<IMsg>(_ => this.Tx(messages, _));

    var _ = ObserveAsync(action.Completion);

    this._inboundMessageBuffer.LinkTo(block);
  }

  public Task Completion { get { return _tcs.Task; } }
}
```

`Completion` starts in a non-completed state. Any number of blocks can be linked to it using `ObserveAsync`. As soon as one of the blocks completes, `Completion` also completes. I wrote `ObserveAsync` here in a way so that if the first completed block completes without error, then so will `Completion`; and if the first completed block completes with an exception, then `Completion` will complete with that same exception. Feel free to tweak for your specific needs. :)

Comment: Thanks this looks hundreds just one comment, you are discarding the result of ObserveAsync? That doesn't weaken the solution?

Comment: @Jim: That would usually be a mistake, but in this case any exceptions/results get reported through `Completion`, so we don't need the task returned from `ObserveAsync`. Another valid option is to make `ObserveAsync` be `async void`, but I prefer this pattern.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution that uses exclusively tools of the TPL Dataflow library itself. You can create a `TransformBlock` that will "process" the `ActionBlock`s you want to observe. Processing a block means simply awaiting for its completion. So the `TransformBlock` takes incomplete blocks, and outputs the same blocks as completed. The `TransformBlock` must be configured with unlimited parallelism and capacity, and with ordering disabled, so that all blocks are observed concurrently, and each one that completes is returned instantly.

```
var allBlocks = new TransformBlock<ActionBlock<IMsg>, ActionBlock<IMsg>>(async block =>
{
    try { await block.Completion; }
    catch { }
    return block;
}, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions()
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = DataflowBlockOptions.Unbounded,
    EnsureOrdered = false
});
```

Then inside the `LinkerThingBob.LinkTo` method, send the created `ActionBlock`s to the `TransformBlock`.

```
var actionBlock = new ActionBlock<IMsg>(_ => this.Tx(messages, _));
allBlocks.Post(actionBlock);
```

Now you need a target to receive the first faulted block. A [`WriteOnceBlock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.writeonceblock-1) is quite suitable for this role, since it ensures that will receive at most one faulted block.

```
var firstFaulted = new WriteOnceBlock<ActionBlock<IMsg>>(x => x);

allBlocks.LinkTo(firstFaulted, block => block.Completion.IsFaulted);
```

Finally you can `await` at any place for the completion of the `WriteOnceBlock`. It will complete immediately after receiving a faulted block, or it may never complete if it never receives a faulted block.

```
await firstFaulted.Completion;
```

After the awaiting you can also get the faulted block if you want.

```
ActionBlock<IMsg> faultedBlock = firstFaulted.Receive();
```

The `WriteOnceBlock` is special on how it behaves when it forwards messages. Unlike most other blocks, you can call multiple times its `Receive` method, and you'll always get the same single item it contains (it is not removed from its buffer after the first `Receive`).