# How can I add timeout to this code

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library, async-await

I am trying to add timeout to this code, but because I am new to this, I can't figure out,

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
     Aspose.Words.Document doc = new Aspose.Words.Document(inputFileName);
     doc.Save(Path.ChangeExtension(inputFileName, ".pdf"));
});
```

Also I want main thread to wait here until it timeout for 5 minutes or completes.

**Edit**

Or can I use cancellation token with this, if yes then how :( ?

Comment: Check this link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nikhil_agarwal/archive/2014/04/02/10511934.aspx

Comment: Relevant question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16605223/c-sharp-task-factory-timeout

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a new `Task` using `Task.Delay` and use `Task.WhenAny`:

```
Task delayedTask = Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
Task workerTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
     Aspose.Words.Document doc = new Aspose.Words.Document(inputFileName);
     doc.Save(Path.ChangeExtension(inputFileName, ".pdf"));
});

if (await Task.WhenAny(delayedTask, workerTask) == delayedTask)
{
   // We got here because the delay task finished before the workertask.
}
else
{
   // We got here because the worker task finished before the delay.
}
```

You can use [`Microsoft.Bcl.Async`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/) to add `async-await` abilities to .NET 4.0

**Edit:**

As you're using VS2010, you can use `Task.Factory.ContinueWheAny` instead:

```
Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAny(new[] { delayedTask, workerTask }, task =>
{
    if (task == delayedTask)
    {
        // We got here if the delay task finished before the workertask.
    }
    else
    {
        // We got here if the worker task finished before the delay.
    }
});
```

**Edit 2:**

Since `Task.Delay` isn't available in .NET 4.0, you can create it yourself using an Extension Method:

```
public static class TaskExtensions
{
    public static Task Delay(this Task task, TimeSpan timeSpan)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        timer.Elapsed += (obj, args) =>
        {
            tcs.TrySetResult(true);
        };
        timer.Interval = timeSpan.Milliseconds;
        timer.AutoReset = false;
        timer.Start();
        return tcs.Task;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer, but do i need to add any assembly as I am receiving these errors, http://prntscr.com/5k07ly

Comment: Yes, you need to add the assemblies via `NuGet`. I added a link in the post

Comment: I like this answer. @YuvalItzchakov does WhenAny cancel the other task execution after first one completes? What is the correct way to afterwards find out which Task was completed?

Comment: No, it doesn't cancel it. But if you pass a `CancellationToken` to it, you can cancel it yourself. As for your second question, i've edited my code.

Comment: Okay! I would assume the first thing we want to do after first Task completes is to cancel the second running Task :)

Comment: You *could* cancel the task if needed. Simply pass the `CancellationToken` and invoke it from inside the `if-else`. Note the `Task` being cancelled will have to monitor the `CancellationToken` in use `ThrowIfCancellationRequested`.

Comment: thanks, but shame I am using Visual Studio 2010 and there is no way i can add nuget package to it :(

Comment: it says Task has no definition for delay - http://prntscr.com/5k0f76

Comment: @CustomizedName See my second edit.

Comment: Delay method still taking 1 parameter but expecting 2 :( sorry me new to this

Comment: @CustomizedName Make sure you have this `this` modifier inside the methods signature declaration: `public static Task Delay(this Task task, TimeSpan timeSpan)`