# C# wait for multiple tasks and abort tasks that take longer than X milliseconds to complete

Tags: c#, task

I'm using C# task library.
What I want to achieve is the following:

- I want to create multiple tasks
- I want to abort tasks that take longer than X milliseconds
- I want to do work after all tasks are completed or aborted
- I don't want the task to throw an exception when it's aborted or if it throws exception it should not interfere with other tasks.

  ```
  foreach (var thing in things)
  {
      var newTask = taskFactory.StartNew(() => this.doStuff(thing));
      tasks.Add(newTask);
  }

  Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
  // Do work after all tasks are completed or aborted
  ```

Comment: You can use a cancellation token, but it depends on how your `doStuff` is implemented, it will need to take the cancellation token and periodically check for the task being cancelled and exit the operation. A task won't unilaterally stop work because its cancelled, its just a signalling mechanism to tell the task it needs to stop.

Comment: Well doStuff calls a controller via TCP and it hangs sometimes. That's why I wan't to force abort the task after X milliseconds. Because I have no control over the logic that calls the controller via TCP

Comment: You may need to use threads, but even in that case `Thread.Abort` is not guaranteed to abort the thread either, the appropriate read/write timeouts should be used on the TCP socket in order to help with aborting and not hanging.

Comment: I think you will find your answer here [C# task factory timeout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16605223/c-sharp-task-factory-timeout)