# Watch async task duration

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

I am using

```
Task task = new Task(action);
task.Start();
```

to call the API of a 3rd party library a lot. Usually this task doesn't take longer than a second.

But I have a suspicion that sometimes the task is hanging and therefore creating a thread leak.

Is there a way to check from the outside whether the execution of this task takes longer than x seconds?

I thought about spawning another task/timer inside the task to measure it, or polling the `Task.Status` permanently, but maybe there is a more elegant way?

Comment: if it hangs, im not sure you have much option - you could use a taskqueue, and then you can ask if all have completed or not. You can then issue death threats on the remaining tasks, but if its proper hung it wont make a difference.

Comment: When you don't know much about a problematic subject, it helps to describe your actual observations instead of your suspicions.

Comment: Can you show us what the `action` is actually doing? This is question is currently too broad.

Comment: @CodeCaster: to explain that would be too much for this question.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: it is calling just one function in a 3rd Party API, which is then in charge of turning on some LEDs in a piece of proprietary hardware.

Comment: Define "from the outside" - do you mean from another thread within your process? Or from another process (e.g. from a "Task Manager" or debugger)?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever i mean from the calling part of code. so maybe another thread, yeah.

Comment: See [this previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16607800/1260204), I think this is exactly what you want to do. In a nutshell, it sets a duration and then cancels the task if it exceeds that duration and handles the exception.

Comment: @Igor That cancels the task, not the operation that the task represents.

Comment: @Servy - I was thinking it could be retrofited to record/log (whatever) the fact that the operation exceeded the duration in the `catch (OperationCanceledException ex)` block. Sorry, after re reading my comment it was not clear (I made the jump in my head without writing it in the comment).

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

```
if(task.Wait(new TimeSpan(0,0,x)))
{
  //completed in x seconds
}
else
{
  //didn't complete
}
```

Comment: The thing is that if it times out, then "The interval defined by timeout elapses. In this case, the current thread resumes execution and the method returns false.", thus killing the task. I think the OP wants to handle differently this case and not kill it.

Comment: @TamasIonut - no it doesn't. No where in the [Task.Wait documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235606(v=vs.110).aspx) does it say the task is killed. You can test it out by changing the `if` to a `while` statement, it will reevaluate until the task completes.

Answer (score 1):

```
Stopwath stop = new Stopwatch();
stop.Start();
Task task = new Task(action);
task.ContinueWith(()=>{stop.Stop();})
task.Start();
```

Then you will be able to see in Elapsed property how much time the task took.